# Is it possible to use the micro USB on Google Glass to connect to another type of micro USB device for data transfer while the Glass is in use?

Tags: google-glass

Is it possible to use the micro USB on Google Glass to connect to another type of micro USB device for data transfer while the Glass is in use? This is basically for a sensor that has a micro USB output but can't be sent over WIFI or Bluetooth due to industry regulations. Obviously, I'd have to write some software but my question is in terms of the hardware itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=258

It would appear from dmesg that the google glass hardware supports USB host mode with an OTG cable, however the system configuration at the time of those messages did not.  There's a suggestion that this can be modified by rooting the device.

In other words, it would appear to be possible - a system configuration task needs to be performed, and then the Android USB Host APIs could likely be used **by a software developer** (ie, the problem is on-topic here).

It could also be worth checking to see if the ADK mode (where the external device is the USB host) would be workable, or if not that then a somewhat hack-y embedded implementation of an ADB host.

Comment: Impressive answer. Also worth noting something that acts like a USB keyboard may work out of the box, such as a barcode reader that pretends to be a keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Yup!  Check out the [ADK protocol](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/index.html). I've used it successfully with Glass. It has the added benefit of charging Glass while you use it for data since the USB Host is on the accessory side.

There are plenty of development boards to make this easier. Like [this Arduino Mega board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11061).