# how to transfer Bi-directional data transfer between google glass and android through USB

Tags: android, usb, google-glass

I want to transfer data bi-directionally over USB between an Android tablet and a Google Glass. Is this possible?, If YES then please provide me some example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the Android Debug Bridge (ADB) for many things.  Consider using that.

If you are asking about some sort of "normal" process to use with a Glass GDK app to use the USB cable then do NOT do this.  You should only consider using USB for development and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to do this for debugging purposes. But this is for **debugging purposes only** (as Erstwhilelll said) - it is not something that you could use for an actual app in practice, especially connected to a tablet.

So for what you're asking, the answer is no.

There are other methods of communicating between the tablet and the Glass. The easiest of the possibilities is sending data over bluetooth. For this, see [this StackOverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20414642/4015623). You can find the code for Bluetooth data transfer here: https://github.com/NathanielWaggoner/GoogleGlassBlutooth

Comment: actually I successfully implemented communication through BT but i'm not able to route audio from TAB to glass over BT. Thats why I thing if USB can solve my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20359572/is-it-possible-to-use-the-micro-usb-on-google-glass-to-connect-to-another-type-o

Comment: @Gurmail very interesting. I do maintain that bluetooth is a better way to do this sort of connection, unless you'll be passing large amounts of data and speed is an issue....

Comment: Yes speed is very big issue in my case. Because when i'm trying to pass byte data (converted audio stream) over BT then lot of data lost. any suggestion "how to pass stream audio to glass over BT or USB?"